# Sass nth-child nesting

Tags: css, sass

I'm refactoring these CSS selectors over to Sass:

```
#romtest .detailed th:nth-child(2),
#romtest .detailed th:nth-child(4),
#romtest .detailed th:nth-child(6),
#romtest .detailed td:nth-child(2),
#romtest .detailed td:nth-child(3),
#romtest .detailed td:nth-child(6),
#romtest .detailed td:nth-child(7),
#romtest .detailed td.last:nth-child(2),
#romtest .detailed td.last:nth-child(4) {
  background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

...and came up with this:

```
#romtest .detailed {
    th:nth-child {
        &(2), &(4), &(6) {
            background:#e5e5e5;
        }
    }
    td:nth-child {
        &(2), &(3), &(6), &(7) {
            background:#e5e5e5;
        }
    }
    td.last:nth-child {
        &(2), &(4) {
            background:#e5e5e5;         
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is throwing an error:

> Invalid CSSS after "&": expected "{", was "(2), &(4), &(6) {"

I also know this could be better because I'm:

- repeating the background color
- repeating numbers - i.e. (2) and (6)

How should I refactor these selectors?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'd be careful about trying to get too clever here. I think it's confusing as it is and using more advanced `nth-child` parameters will only make it more complicated. As for the background color I'd just set that to a variable.

Here goes what I came up with before I realized trying to be too clever might be a bad thing.

```
#romtest {
 $bg: #e5e5e5;
 .detailed {
    th {
      &:nth-child(-2n+6) {
        background-color: $bg;
      }
    }
    td {
      &:nth-child(3n), &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(7) {
        background-color: $bg;
      }
      &.last {
        &:nth-child(-2n+4){
          background-color: $bg;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is a quick demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEImD

**----EDIT----**

Here's another approach to avoid retyping `background-color`:

```
#romtest {
  %highlight {
    background-color: #e5e5e5; 
  }
  .detailed {
    th {
      &:nth-child(-2n+6) {
        @extend %highlight;
      }
    }

    td {
      &:nth-child(3n), &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(7) {
        @extend %highlight;
      }
      &.last {
        &:nth-child(-2n+4){
          @extend %highlight;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to do `&(2), &(4)` which won't work

```
#romtest {
  .detailed {
    th {
      &:nth-child(2) {//your styles here}
      &:nth-child(4) {//your styles here}
      &:nth-child(6) {//your styles here}
      }
  }
}
```