# How to get nth value from color list in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have a color list and I need to get the nth value from the list. I tried the below code to get color value

```
$grad: #000000, #ffffff;
$first: nth($grad, 1);
$second: nth($grad, 2);
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any thing I missed? Is there any inbuilt function which supports to get the colors from a color list (All supported format like hexa, rgb, rgba, hsl etc..)?

Comment: see this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499850/sass-nth-child-nesting

Comment: So I tested this out for you and it seems to work fine. there are 2 colors assigned to $grad: #000000 (black), #ffffff (white). $first is black, and $second is white.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is due to the argument in the mixin. If I set multi value argument ($list...) it doesn't get nth value from the list.

```
@mixin list($list...){
  @if($list == none){
    .none{
      color: black;
    }
  }
  @else{
    $n: nth($list, 1);
    .color-#{$n}{
       color: $n;
    }
  }
}

$lis: red, blue;
@include list(none);
@include list($lis);
```

If I removed (...) from the mixin argument its working perfectly. It may be an issue

Comment: Your provided code did not contain a [MCVE], making this answer make absolutely no sense in context.  This question has absolutely no value to future visitors, you should have deleted it rather than post an answer that won't help anyone.